# Is an alternating sequence never divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

My question:

lets say the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is alternating and *not against* $0$, to avoid the Leibniz criterion.

Is that said sequence always divergent then?

Comment: Please try to format your questions properly.  See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: What do you mean "not against zero"? The [definition of an alternating series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series) is quite clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean:

> Suppose $a_n \geq 0$, and $a_n \not \rightarrow 0$. Is is true that the series $\Sigma _{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n a_n$ diverges?

Then the answer is that the series can't possibly converge to a real number, because the terms of a convergent series always converge to zero. No conclusion can be made about if it diverges to $\pm \infty$ or just doesn't converge at all.